# How do I deploy a web application on tomcat so that I can access it using only IP?

Tags: tomcat8

How to deploy my web-application on Tomcat so that it can be accessed by using IP of the server alone?

Note: I have Tomcat running on port 80.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I edited your question to make it more readable and to include an actual question mark. (Note that a blank line is needed to separate paragraphs. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more details on the syntax.) I also fixed some minor spelling issues.

Please edit your question to indicate how you *can* already access your application and to tell what happens when you try to access it by using the IP alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to deploy tour application in the ROOT context (rename your app.war to ROOT.war). Check if there is on webapps directory of tomcat the default ROOT webapp that comes with it.